# Create dynamic Card View from values from api in react web. I am new to react js. How to crearte dynamic card view in react js based on object?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a list of card views from the data received from API.
For example, I have a student object. I want to create a card where student name student time and student class and also one button to admit student in class on the same card. I am new to react js.

[image: Just Like this]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Generally you would store the fetched data in an array and use `array.prototype.map` to map the data to the JSX you want rendered. See [Lists & Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). I suggest referring to official React docs for just about any question you have, they are very informative and well maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your array of students and render a card for each student as following using foreach array method , you can choose another methods to loop through your array:

```
StudentsArray.forEach((element))=>{
    return(
      <Card name={element.name} id={element.id}/>
    )
}
```

Check for each loop reference [Array.prototype.foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

for more check this out [loop through an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

**Update:** ForEach does not return any value. use map() instead as the following example: [Array.map()](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/loop)

Comment: ForEach does not return any value. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp